# How to get all child's data in firebase and show it into my android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in my Firebase Real-time database :

[image]

How can I count the data and show it in my app, which listener shall I use to get all childrens?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways in which you could achieve this. 
I use the following way:

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .child("demografi")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                YourObject object = dataSnap.getValue(YourObject.class);

                                // Use your object as needed
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

`dataSnapshot` returns the child referenced. Once you have it, all you have to do is iterate through them and you have access to "all children" as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child("demografi")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    /** Qty of data in demografi, this is what you want. */
                    long Count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

if you want to monitor the count of data in realtime way,

you have to replace [addListenerForSingleValueEvent] with [addValueEventListener].

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer this way -

```
String email, gender, nama;
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("demografi");

databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        // To get children count
        dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

        email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
        gender = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
        nama = dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue().toString();
        // and so on..
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a model class, you can simply use the String class. So to get all child's data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference demografiRef = rootRef.child("demografi");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String nama = ds.child("nama").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", nama);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
demografiRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be all the names of all your users. As you can see, there is a second log statement which will print the total number of your children.